# Usage/connotation of "いろ" meaning someone's "girl/lover"

Tags: word-choice, words, connotation

In Rurouni Kenshin, a woman is running away from Kanryuu's men. A guy asks her "are you Kanryuu's girl?" (anta wa Kanryuu no iro ka?)

Anyways, my question is the usage of "iro" to mean one's girl/lover (since I haven't heard it before). Is it an out-dated term (Rurouni Kenshin takes place during the early Meiji era iirc)? Is it considered vulgar/impolite? And is it usually written in kanji, or hiragana, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is listed in [goo dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D/#jn-15685) as follows:

> ８
>
> ㋐情事。色事。「―を好む」「―に溺れる」
>
> ㋑女性の美しい容貌。「―に迷う」
>
> **㋒情人。恋人。いい人。「―をつくる」**

It is simply dated and vulgar (impolite does not seem to fit - it's not really used now). My impression is that it is often used in Jidai-geki (=Japanese historical drama mostly set in Edo era, which was popular in Showa Era).